# chromium DevTools Recorder not exist

Tags: chromium, devtools, recorder

We are using Chromium DevTools Recorder,
In Chromium 92 we were able to find this item (it was experimental).
now in chromium 99 I am not able to find the Recorder.
this feature exists in chrome but not in Chromium do you know how I can activate it.

Thanks

Comment: I can't find it too, neither in Chromium 100 via apt package nor in Chromium 101 via snap. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

It is a Chrome-only feature, and not available in Chromium.

source: https://groups.google.com/g/google-chrome-developer-tools/c/CN_CKHw71aI

Answer (score 0):

In Chromium 116 (August 2023), the Recorder plugin is now available in DevTools (under More Tools).